# Download TFS Changeset files using batch files

Tags: batch-file, changeset

Is is  possible to have a batch file which will download all files in a change set number to a specific location.

Answer (score 1):

The following command will help you to get TFS changeset in command line:

```
tf changeset [/comment:("comment"|@commentfile)] 
[/notes:("NoteFieldName"="NoteFieldValue"|@notefile)] [/noprompt][/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl]] 
[changesetnumber | /latest][/login:username,[password]]
```

The same can be tried from a batch file as well I suppose.

Before calling that, the specified location you want this changeset can be mapped as Workspace by calling the command below:

```
tf workspace /new [/noprompt] [/template:workspacename[;workspaceowner]]
[/computer:computername] [/comment:("comment"|@comment file)]
[/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] [/permission:(Private|PublicLimited|Public)][workspacename[;workspaceowner]][/login:username,[password]]
tf workfold [/map serverfolder localfolder] [/collection:TeamProjectCollectionUrl] [/workspace:workspacename][/login:username,[password]
```

Comment: I want to download the files to a specific folder is it possible ?

Comment: `localfolder` in the `tf workfold` command, you need to give the folder you want it to download, it will map it first to that by that `tf workfold` command

Comment: is it necessary to bind it with workspace, actually my requirement is to download a list of database scripts ( which are updated by developers) and download them to a specific new folder and execute them in database.

Comment: Ya, I think Workspace binding may not be required if you use command like `tf workfold $/projects/MyTeamProject/* C:\MyLocalWorkfold\MyTeamProject`. But, I am not sure about that.